# .split() working weird on some strings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a string with spaces on the keypress of a contenteditable div. But the split is working very wierdly.

Just try to run the below code once:

```js
var d = "mod india jned cjkdem demdjkjncj kdeknd kmdke kmdekmd".split(" ");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

The expected output should be an array of all the words.

Comment: How is it behaving weirdly? I ran the code snippet, appears fine to me.

Comment: do you have spaces or tabs (or any other whitespace) in between those words?

Comment: @xunatai ?? Did you notice that some of the result strings in the array have spaces?

Comment: @xunatai the final array  should have 8 elements. The output has just 5. Look closely.

Comment: I bet its because the string isn't containing only "real" whitespaces between words. To fix that look at `trincot`'s answer.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, I see now.

Comment: If I replace all the spaces in between the words with an actual space char, it works fine.  You must have some other white-space (not an actual space char, - like a tab) in between those words

Answer (score 8):

You have some white space characters that are not normal spaces (but non-breaking spaces). To catch them also, use the regular expression `/\s/`, like so:

```js
var d = "mod india jned cjkdem demdjkjncj kdeknd kmdke kmdekmd".split(/\s/);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here is how you can see which white space characters you have, using `charCodeAt(0)`:

```js
var d = "mod india jned cjkdem demdjkjncj kdeknd kmdke kmdekmd".match(/\s/g)
       .map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0));
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

The code 32 represents the normal space, while 160 is the code of a [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

Comment: I feel like this answer would be more awesome if it had a reference to "gotta catch'em all"

Comment: And what can be those "not normal spaces" characters can be?

Comment: They are [non-breaking spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) in this case, but there exist other white space characters that could occur as well, which `/\s/` will all catch.

Comment: Sometimes pasting strings from Word or other programs, it can contain weird spaces

Comment: It's amazing how an answer to a question that should have been closed gets more upvotes in 10 minutes than I get in most days...